# Domain name Availability Python script

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I am currently working on a project for a web hosting company. They would like to have a domain name search feature on their website. Where a customer can type in the domain name they would like and see if it's available or not. Once they have found an available name then it would save it to the order.

I am currently building the website using html, CSS, Python and Flask.

I am wondering if there is a way to create something like this? Do I need to use a different language for this?

Look forward to your replies.

Comment: Research it online.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***>>>[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=domain+name+avaliablility+api&oq=domain+name+avaliablility+api)<<<***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)